# Use of DatePicker

Tags: c#, .net-maui

I'm trying .net maui platform, I created a form containing DatePicker. I would like everything to be in French (dd-mm-yyyy) unfortunately the result is always in English (mm-dd-yyyy). I've tried everything "format" in the XAML and format through c#, but nothing works.

Comment: You may need to set the culture info somewhere

Comment: To expand on @PeterSmith's comment, UI elements are localized using a _Culture_ (like fr-FR or fr-CA or en-US).  If you want something other that what you are getting _out-of-the-box_, then you'll need to adjust your culture (the culture includes both the language and the locale - French Canadian being different from France)

Answer (score 2):

Since your aren't specifying if you are using the built in DatePicker or a thirdparty one I'm assuming you are using the built-in version.
I'm also missing some information on what you've already tried, so I'm going to give you the simplest answer.

Firstly, take a look at the documentation for the DatePicker in .NET MAUI [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/datepicker)

The DatePicker contains a format property that works like any C# date formatting.
What you want is something like "dd/mm/yyyy" or similar.

The formatting can be done from both XAML and C# - In XAML it would look like this:

```
<DatePicker Format="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
```

And in C# something like this:

```
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker
{
    Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
}
```

For a detailed documentation on the string formatting available in .NET you can look in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 2):

The `format` property of the DatePicker only works on Android. On Windows platform, it is not working properly.

In addition, there is a known issue about this problem on Github. You can follow it up here:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7972.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will wait for the update to be published